# Append a text on a specefic row of a TextArea

Tags: javascript

```js
let someText = "Hi THIS IS MY TEXT AND I WANT IT CENTRED NOT ON THE TOP OF THE TEXTAREA"; //This would be replaced with your textarea value
let stringSplit = someText.split("\n");

if (stringSplit.length < 8) {
  //Add enough items to be 8 rows
  for (let x = stringSplit.length; x < 8; x++) {
    stringSplit.push("");
  }
}

//replace the 8th row value with your name
stringSplit[7] = "YourName";

//Join the array back into a string separated by newline between each element value
someText = stringSplit.join("\n");
//Set your textarea value = someText
console.log(someText);
```

With this code I am able to add value on the 8th row, but the problem is that my text will be like this:

```
    EXEMPLE OF TEXT






       VALUE(8throw)
```

Instead of

```
            /n
            /n
            /n
        MY TEXT


       Value(8th row)
```

I want to let my text centred , and the value to be on the 8th row, instead of having my text on the top of the textarea, an my value on the bottom.
I want to replace the 3 breakline by my text to make something like this.

```
\n \n \n Mytext \n \n \n Value
```

What I want to achieve is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gveLo.png)

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/) of your problem

Comment: Are you saying that you don't want it to scroll the textarea content such that it reveals the last line instead of the first? Or vice versa? Is there a reason you're not giving a real code demo?

Comment: Check my edited question.

Comment: Your description is confusing. Keep it simple. Are you saying that after adding text, you want the last line of the `textarea` to be showing? Or the first line? Or something else?

Comment: @CrazyTrain I have a checkbox as soon as i click on it, i have an element which is appended to the 8th row. 
My problem is when it's appended to the 8th row.
it pushes all my text.
As Exemple : i write Hello, after that i click the button to append my value in the 8th row.
it will push my text to the top, instead of letting it on the middle.

Comment: Yeah, I have no idea what you mean by "pushes all my text". Like I said, your description is confusing. Just answer my question. Is the problem that there is some text in the `textarea` that is not visible because there's not enough room? If so, is it the top or the bottom of the text that you want to see?

Comment: Well, whatever. I'll assume that you want to be able to see the new text at the bottom. So try this below the code you show: `this.message.scrollTop = this.message.scrollHeight;`

Comment: @CrazyTrain Sorry if i'm not too clear, the text as the begining is centred, when i write a new line it goes up. that's ok.
but u don't want it to go TOP as soon as i click to add the value, i want to keep it acting normal with the value on the 8th row.
I want it to keep the centred text on the textarea even if i click to add the line on the 8th row, i think the "/n" is acting weirdly

Answer (score 1):

Add to the beginning and the end of the array alternatively:

```js
let someText = "Example text";
let stringSplit = someText.split("\n");
for (let x = stringSplit.length; x < 8; x++) {
  if (x % 2 == 0) {
    stringSplit.unshift("");
  } else {
    stringSplit.push("");
  }
}
stringSplit[7] = "Last line";
console.log(stringSplit.join("\n"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let string = "Example text";
let stringSplit = string.split("\n");
for (let x = stringSplit.length; x < 7; x++) {
  if (x % 2 == 0) {
    stringSplit.unshift("");
  } else {
    stringSplit.push("");
  }
}
stringSplit[7] = "Last line";
console.log(stringSplit.join("\n"));
```